# Если ssh внезапно закрывается, как сохранить результаты работы на удалённом хосте?

Tags: ssh, консоль, shell

Иногда открытая сессия SSH может внезапно закрыться (`broken pipe`), например при работе через GPRS/wi-fi с плохим качеством сигнала.

Если в момент разрыва на удалённом хосте что-то происходило (копирование большого списка файлов, сборка ПО из исходных кодов, или был открыт текстовый редактор), то результаты работы этого "чего-то" в большинстве случаев теряются. Это очень раздражает, как этого избежать?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

То, что Вам нужно, называется консольный мультиплексор. Идея в том, чтобы на удалённом хосте запустить процесс, который будет как бы "сохранять состояние консоли", независимо от того, есть ли в данный момент активная сессия (ssh или физического доступа к хосту "через клавиатуру и монитор") работы с этой консолью.

Сценарий действий будет таков:

1. коннектимся к удалённому хосту по ssh
2. запускаем терминальный мультиплексор
3. начинаем работать
4. соединение рвётся
5. восстанавливаем соединение
6. восстанавливаем сеанс работы с терминальным мультиплексором
7. продолжаем работать с того же самого места, где остановились, ничего не потеряв

Это удобно также для того, чтобы продолжить работу с другого комьютера, или передать работу над текущей консольной задачей коллеге.

Самые популярные консольные мультиплексоры - `screen` (прост в освоении, минимальный функционал) и `tmux` (несколько более сложен, но намного более функционален - например, позволяет в рамках одной сессии tmux открыть сразу несколько экземпляров терминала и выводить их в консоль одновременно, разделив экран на несколько произвольных областей).

Изучение ключей командной строки для команд `screen` и `tmux` оставлю на совести читателя.

Comment: screen вроде тоже умеет делить экран. Хотя гарантировать не могу.

Comment: @Etki Да, умеет, сам пользую. (А ещё настроил себе вывод строки состояния с временем и нагрузкой)

Comment: И про этот тоже)

Answer (score 5):

Установите `screen`

```
sudo apt-get install screen
```

Сразу после подключения к ssh создайте новую сессию

```
screen
```

после рекконекта к ней можно подключиться вызовом

```
screen -r
```

Команда "два в одном" - подключение к существующей сессии или создание новой, если существующей нет:

```
screen -D -r
```

Answer (score 2):

mosh + (по желанию) tmux или screen

Comment: старайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Добавьте пояснения. Опишите, на чем основан ваш ответ.